# Ag Grid how to override message to display error from server

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have ag grid and want to display error from controller written in C# in .NET Core.
Now I can display custom message when any rows are loaded:

```
function ServerSideDatasource(server, projectListComponent) {
  return {

    getRows: function (params) {
     // debugger;
      var response = server.getData(params.request).then((res) => {
        debugger;

        if (res.status === 'Error') {
         // projectListComponent.setOverlayNoRowsTemplate("<p>sdfdssfdf</p>");
          projectListComponent.overlayNoRowsTemplate = "<p>vvvvv</p>";
          params.parentNode.gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay();
        }
```

In html:

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 700px;">
                 ...
                 [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate">
  >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

this is method in TypeScript:

```
setOverlayNoRowsTemplate(template) {
    this.overlayNoRowsTemplate = template;
  }
```

and in constructor in TypeScript I set template for message when there are no rows:

```
this.setOverlayNoRowsTemplate("<p>There is no data</p>");
```

And when any row is loaded I see message that is set in constructor. I can't set this template in getRows method.
I want to use this way to display error from controller that is written in C#.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?